# How can I check boot disk size consumption used in GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have been using a GKE cluster with 10GB of boot disk size for my pods. Yesterday, I have added two more pods and I have been getting warnings of node under disk pressure.

I have read this might be due to the 10GB and I would like to know how to check what it is using this space. I do not have a very high number of pods and I have persistent volume claims which use a different space so I do not understand what it is consuming more than 10GB.

Thank you in advance and regards.

Answer (score 2):

In order to a sense of which pods are taking space you might use the following metric

[pod/volume/utilization](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes)

> The fraction of the volume that is currently being used by the
> instance. This value cannot be greater than 1 as usage cannot exceed
> the total available volume space. Sampled every 60 seconds. After
> sampling, data is not visible for up to 120 seconds.

Menu > Monitoring > Metrics explorer > resource type kubernetes pod (k8s) > Metric Volume Utilization

Comment: Thank you very much! I have taken a look and my DB is the one requesting more, almost half the utilization (0.4). However, if I take a look at volume usage rather than volume utilization, the value is around 500MB. I do not understand as 500MB is very little compared to the 10GB boot disk size. This volume metric seems to be linked to their persistent volume which 1GB and not the cluster book disk size which is what I am looking for.